# How can I define zstyle completion preference for a zsh alias?

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

If I have an executable - say `~/bin/stuff` in my `PATH`, I can define this in my `.zshrc` to have it autocomplete text files first as arguments to my command:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:stuff:*' file-patterns '*.txt:all-files' '*:all-files'
```

However, if `stuff` is an alias - e.g `alias stuff=less`, then this doesn't work anymore - and zsh just pretends like it should autocomplete to all-files as that's the default.

I've looked at the docs here - [Zsh Completion System](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) and not found anything more than talk of how to expand an alias - which is not what I'm looking for.

I *think* it's because the docs say argument pattern for `zstyle` is `':completion:*:*:-command-:*:commands'`, but does that mean that the fourth section must be a *command* and not an *alias*. I always assumed they were more or less interchangeable in zsh.

I mean I can create a bunch one line executables that just have my alias followed by `"$@"` in them - but that's just not *elegant*.

Comment: I have found a workaround where I define the pattern as simply `':completion:*'` so it suggests text files first for _all_ commands. This is not ideal, but suffices for now. I would still like this question answered though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming tab is mashed after `stuff` in both these cases

```
% ls
bar     foo.txt
% whence stuff
% alias stuff=less
% zstyle ':completion:*:*:stuff:*' file-patterns '*.txt:all-files'
% stuff
bar      foo.txt
```

a relevant knob from `zshoptions(1)` is

```
COMPLETE_ALIASES
    Prevents aliases on the command line from being internally sub-
    stituted before completion is attempted. The effect is to make
    the alias a distinct command for completion purposes.
```

so

```
% setopt COMPLETE_ALIASES
% stuff foo.txt
```

as otherwise the alias is already something else.

To check for side effects we should confirm that this change does not break completion on aliases for which there is no completion or style configuration,

```
% setopt COMPLETE_ALIASES
% whence foo
% unfunction _foo
unfunction: no such hash table element: _foo
% alias foo=ls
% foo (eval):1: command not found: _foo
```

so with `COMPLETE_ALIASES` set you may need to setup completions for each alias, or list or otherwise include the alias name(s) on the appropriate `compdef` e.g.

```
% compdef _ls foo
% foo
...
```

On the other hand I do find `exec` wrappers to be quite elegant, as they unlike shell aliases can be called by `exec(3)` or `system(3)` without the need to load up a rather large shell or pollute what should be a simple system call with interactive shell configuration.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this today and report back.

Comment: Yup! This works. Doesn't seem to have any side effects that I have seen yet.